# Spotify API blocked by CORS Policy - localhost

Tags: api, spotify

I have seen more than a handful of posts regarding the same issue but none of the suggestions have worked.

I am attempting to connect to Spotify's `/authorize` endpoint.

I have supplied the `client_id`, `response_type` (as `token`), and provided a `redirect_uri` which is
`http://localhost:80/callback/`

I have also whitelisted this uri **exactly as it is above** along with other variants.

Here is the full request uri (`client_id` modified)
`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=123456789&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A80%2Fcallback%2F&scope=playlist-modify-public%2Cplaylist-modify-private%2Cuser-library-modify%2Cplaylist-read-private`

My localhost is WAMP and it is indeed pointing listening on port `80`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use a HTTP library to an OAuth2 authorization endpoint, you are supposed to redirect the user's browser directly there.

The idea is that the user itself must go to spotify.com and grant your application access.